# How to make perl skip certain words during search and replace

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to do HTML highlighting if words in a file match certain key words/names. However there are times when part of a key word is also present and Perl matches it again.

For e.g. I have the following key words

1. `KY SPINE & REHAB`  - when found replace with square brackets around it
2. `SPINE`  - when found replace with round brackets around it
3. `REHAB` - when found replace with round brackets around it

Once it matches with `KY SPINE & REHAB` , I want to stop it from matching `SPINE` and `REHAB`.

This is what I get now. I cant give HTML examples because I dont know how to display HTML tags as this website translates it and only displays the text. In reality I am trying to highlight these keywords with different colours based on which set they are coming from.

What I get now:

```
[KY (SPINE) & (REHAB)]
```

What I want is:

```
[KY SPINE & REHAB]
```

How do I make Perl skip words while doing search and replace?

I have millions of records for which I have to do this and even with parallel processing its not that fast. So code efficient suggestions will be appreciated.

As an update, I have hundreds of keywords and any keyword could be a subset of another keyword. So its not practical to hard code it. I am looking for solutions where perl can skip strings enclosed within then square brackets so that further replacement does not happen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and to learn about formatting of questions and answers. I took the liberty of making it a bit more readable. Please also read [ask] and then add the code you wrote to get your current output and some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If those are the only three phrases that you want to highlight then this will do it for you

```
perl -i -pe's/(KY SPINE & REHAB|SPINE|REHAB)/$1 =~ tr/&// ? "[$1]" : "($1)"/eg' myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/(KY SPINE & REHAB)/[$1]/;
    s/(SPINE(?!.*REHAB)|(?<!SPINE & )REHAB)/($1)/;
    say;
}

__DATA__
KY SPINE & REHAB - when found replace with square brackets around it
SPINE - when found replace with round brackets around it
REHAB - when found replace with round brackets around it
```

**Output:**

```
[KY SPINE & REHAB] - when found replace with square brackets around it
(SPINE) - when found replace with round brackets around it
(REHAB) - when found replace with round brackets around it
```

Comment: That will fail on a record like `xxx xxx SPINE xxx xxx REHAB xxx`. And what's the `chomp` for?

Comment: @Borodin: Yes it will, but it works for the given example. The chomp is needed to avoid double line feed on output.

Comment: The OP has shown no example data. And `print` is a useful alternative to `say` when you don't want to print an additional newline

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This would work if it were a few keywords. There are hundreds of such key words and any one of them can be a subset of the other. What I really want is the ability to skip strings that are enclosed in square brackets. I am actually doing HTML highlighting so I would like to skip strings which have HTML tags around it.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
s/(KY SPINE & REHAB|SPINE|REHAB)/[$1]/g
```

Hope it will work for you either

**EDIT:**

this is a complete code that worked for me. can use it for your case or any other custom replace for any string. this might not be a cool one liner but it works. hope it is better suited for your needs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($new, $last, $offset, $length, $replace);

while(<DATA>) {
    $new = '';
    $last = 0;
    while ($_ =~ m/KY SPINE & REHAB|SPINE|REHAB/g) {
        $offset = $-[0];
        if ($& eq 'KY SPINE & REHAB') {
            $replace = '[' . $& . ']';
        }
        if ($& eq 'SPINE') {
            $replace = '(' . $& . ')';
        }
        if ($& eq 'REHAB') {
            $replace = '(' . $& . ')';
        }
        $length = $offset - $last;
        $new .= substr($_, $last, $length) . $replace;
        $last = $+[0];
    }
    $length = length($_) - $last;
    $new .= substr($_, $last, $length);
    print $new;
}

__DATA__
lorem ipsum KY SPINE & REHAB dolor sit amet SPINE consectetur adipiscing elit REHAB sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua  sit amet SPINE consectetur adipiscing elit REHAB sed do eiusmod tempor
 KY SPINE & REHAB dolor sit amet SPINE consectetur adipiscing elit REHAB sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut amet SPINE consectetur adipiscing elit REHAB sed do eiusmod tempor adipiscing elit REHAB sed do eiusmod tempor
lorem ipsum KY SPINE & REHAB dolor sit amet SPINE consectetur adipiscing elit REHAB sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua  sit amet SPINE consectetur adipiscing elit REHAB sed do eiusmod tempor
SPINE sit amet SPINE consectetur REHAB
SPINE
sit amet SPINE consectetur KY SPINE & REHAB REHAB
```

Comment: Hi Alex- Thanks for answering. Perhaps I didnt ask it properly. I cant do 'OR (|)' here because I need to replace these words differently. So I need to do multiple passes. I have updated the question.

Comment: @LeslieFrancis Hi Leslie I fixed the code. it should work right now for your case.